# How can I enable 'secondary click' on macOS trackpad to work only with a tap, and not by clicking?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, applescript, catalina, automation

In the macOS Trackpad settings, there is an option named 'Secondary click', if this is checked, a two-finger tap or click will open the context menu.

Can I only open the context menu with a two-finger tap, not a two-finger click?

Because I want to set two-finger click to another function using BetterTouchTool.

I tried, disable 'Secondary click' in options, set two-finger tap to 'right click' using BTT, but this triggers right-click very slow, not as quick as the native two-finger tap, (If you disable Smart zoom in Scroll & Zoom in Trackpad settings, two-finger tap will trigger very fast).

[image]

Comment: I think this issue is better taken up with Better Touch Tool - [file a bug report with them](https://community.folivora.ai/c/bug-reports/6). Meanwhile, why don't you set up context menu with three fingers tap using Better Touch Tool after disabling *Look up & data detectors* and *Secondary click* on macOS trackpad settings - you should then be able to configure two finger tap and two finger click more freely with Better Touch Tool? (Another experimental thing you can try is to reduce the *double-clicking* speed in **Mouse** setting and see if that brings up the menu faster).

Comment: @sfxedit I've put a bug report in BTT forum, I'm using 3 dinger tap to look up& data detectors in dictionary